# how Apache htaccess rewrite if the file exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

if file /data/cache/list_game.html exists,user visit /game/ rewrite to it.
else if not ,rewrite to /index.php?m=Home&c=Game&a=lst.

My code of .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond data/cache/list_game.html -f
RewriteRule ^game\/?$ data/cache/list_game.html [L,QSA]
```

but dont work,when file data/cache/list_game.html not exists, throw error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule from your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/data/cache/list_game.html -f
RewriteRule ^game/?$ data/cache/list_game.html [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^game/?$ index.php?m=Home&c=Game&a=lst [L,QSA,NC]
```